# Need a word / exp for instantaneous, effortless perception of displayed data

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I am trying to describe why a certain display doesn't work well. I have to look closely and make an effort to read it, because pixels are too far apart and have low contrast.

I've been looking at 'glance value', 'gestalt principles' but didn't really find a perfect term. It might be somewhere in graphic design, UI design, cognitive science, psychology?

[image: bad display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the display's **[readability](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+readability)**:

> noun
>
> the quality of being legible or decipherable.
>
> *"adding or removing space between lines can drastically improve readability"*
>
> the quality of being easy or enjoyable to read.
>
> *"her prose combines lyricism with readability"*

You could also use the adjective **[readable](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+readability)**:

> adjective
>
> able to be read or deciphered; legible.
>
> **synonyms:** legible, easy to read, decipherable, clear, intelligible, comprehensible, reader-friendly
>
> *"the inscription is perfectly readable"*

If that's not exactly what you're looking for, then it's at least a good place to start a synonym search.